# How to handle discontinuities in a function

Tags: python, 3d, pyvista

I am trying to use pyvista to plot the isosurfaces of some function. However, this function takes values in a circle, and hence between -pi and pi because the circle is parametrized by the angle. Therefore when the angle is close to pi there is a sudden jump to -pi, a discontinuity. When using the `StructuredGrid.contour` method, this causes those branch points to always appear on the graph, because it seems to be interpolating between said values of -pi and pi. Is there any way to avoid this?

EDIT: here's the program I'm running. Changing the value of angle changes the smooth part, but not the blocky artifact at the branch cut.

```
import numpy as np
import pyvista as pv

a = 2
b = 3
theta = 1

def toComplex(x, y, z):
    z1 = 2*x + 2*y*1j
    z2 = 2*z + (x*x + y*y + z*z - 1)*1j
    z1 /= x*x + y*y + z*z + 1
    z2 /= x*x + y*y + z*z + 1
    return [z1, z2]

#%% Data
x, y, z = np.pi*np.mgrid[-2:2:101j, -2:2:101j, -2:2:101j]
complexPoint = toComplex(x, y, z)
argument = np.angle(complexPoint[0]**2 + complexPoint[1]**3)
vol = argument
grid = pv.StructuredGrid(x, y, z)
grid["vol"] = vol.flatten()
contours = grid.contour([theta])

#%% Visualization
pv.set_plot_theme('default')
p = pv.Plotter()
p.add_mesh(contours, scalars=contours.points[:, 2], show_scalar_bar=False)
p.show(interactive_update=False)
```

Comment: You should tell us more about your function. If your function is continuous (despite the jump in phase) then the contour shouldn't have an artifact. If the function is indeed discontinuous then seeing branch cuts in the contours would be reasonable. Adding a [mcve] would help a lot. Somethin we can run to see your issue.

Comment: @AndrasDeak--СлаваУкраїні I've updated the post with the code. The function is continuous when seen as a function to S^1, but discontinuous when seen as a function to [-pi, pi]. My question is precisely how to remove the branch cut.

Comment: OK, having looked at this a bit, I don't think it's true that your function is "continuous on S^1". Your function is the phase, and the phase indeed jumps from -pi to pi at the branch cut. Even if you drew the function over S^1 you would get a jump, because the phase has a jump there (assuming a single branch). So the question is what you really want to plot. If your phase jumps and yet you say it's continuous sounds like you mean that the complex number `exp(i*val)` is continuous where `val` is the function you are plotting now. However it's not clear how you'd expect contouring to work here.

Comment: In other words, 1. check that the function you're trying to contour is indeed what you think it is, 2. try to explain the result you expect to get. I don't think you have a programming problem right now, I suspect you have to figure out the issue on the math side. The "blocky artifact" is always in the same place because you have a region where the angle sharply jumps from -pi to pi, so it doesn't really matter what contour value you use: you always see the sharp transition region.

Comment: The function is continuous if you consider the range to be S^1. The discontinuity comes from parametrizing S^1 as the angle [-pi, pi]. That is, in S^1 -pi = pi and there is no discontinuity.

Comment: More precisely: I'm considering the function f(x,y) = x^a + y^b from C^2 to C, and then doing f/abs(f) where it is defined. This is clearly a continuous function. What I want to plot are the fibers of this function seen in S^3, which I'm parametrizing using stereographic coordinates (that's what the function `toComplex` does).

Comment: OK, but in that sense "S^1" is not a subset of the real line, the only thing that you can plot and contour. You'd want to contour based on a complex number, or equivalently a 2d point. My point is that this is fundamentally impossible to do with regular software unless you can convert your problem into something else.

Comment: Yes, so that's what my question was trying to ask. The software is seeing pi and close to it -pi, and it's guessing that there must be a 1 somewhere in between. I wanted to ask if there is a way to say "no, -pi and pi are too far away, don't fill in that gap please" to the contouring function.